# timer keep values after reload of javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a project on which I am working at the moment, this project is based on the control of the hours of work of an educator. example; the teacher before working, he must start his course while clicking on a button to trigger a miner who will control his number of hours of work. I would like to know how to do if after the teacher to start his course, even if we refresh his page so that the timer continues to count and after his course, he will click on another button for his timer uninitialized.
already thank you for your help ...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<div id="response"></div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    var x;
    var face;
    $(document).on('click', '.AddCourseProintage', function(){


  var one_second = 1000;
  var one_minute = one_second * 60;
  var one_hour = one_minute * 60;
  var one_day = one_hour * 24;
  var startDate = new Date();
  test = document.getElementById('response');
  x = setInterval(function() {

  // Get today's date and time
  var now = new Date().getTime();
  var now = new Date();
  var elapsed = now - startDate;
  var parts = [];

  parts[0] = '' + Math.floor( elapsed / one_hour );
  parts[1] = '' + Math.floor( (elapsed % one_hour) / one_minute );
  parts[2] = '' + Math.floor( ( (elapsed % one_hour) % one_minute ) / one_second );

  parts[0] = (parts[0].length == 1) ? '0' + parts[0]+'h' : parts[0]+'h';
  parts[1] = (parts[1].length == 1) ? '0' + parts[1]+'mn' : parts[1]+'mn';
  parts[2] = (parts[2].length == 1) ? '0' + parts[2]+'s' : parts[2]+'s';
  test.innerText = parts.join(' : ');

       // If the count down is finished, write some text 


}, 1000);


});
});

</script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The example site is gone now, but I answered one like this a while ago:

[How do I store my countdown timer in a cookie so that it will continue counting down even when leaving or reloading the page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46312941/how-do-i-store-my-countdown-timer-in-a-cookie-so-that-it-will-continue-counting/46316258#46316258)