# how can I save the time in the timer, and resume later?

Tags: javascript, timer, electron, electron-forge

so I have a timer and a save file using JSON.
this is how the json file looks like for example:

```
{
  "name": "shinx",
  "imageurl": "https://poketch-cdn-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/images/pokemon/animated/shiny/shinx.gif",
  "method": "pokeradar",
  "counter": 0,
  "shinycharm": false,
  "masuda": false
}
```

here is the timer code:

```
// Convert time to a format of hours, minutes, seconds, and milliseconds

function timeToString(time) {
  let diffInHrs = time / 3600000;
  let hh = Math.floor(diffInHrs);

  let diffInMin = (diffInHrs - hh) * 60;
  let mm = Math.floor(diffInMin);

  let diffInSec = (diffInMin - mm) * 60;
  let ss = Math.floor(diffInSec);

  let diffInMs = (diffInSec - ss) * 100;
  let ms = Math.floor(diffInMs);

  let formattedHH = hh.toString().padStart(2, "0");
  let formattedMM = mm.toString().padStart(2, "0");
  let formattedSS = ss.toString().padStart(2, "0");
  let formattedMS = ms.toString().padStart(2, "0");

  return `${formattedHH}:${formattedMM}:${formattedSS}`;
}

// Declare variables to use in our functions below
let startTime;
let elapsedTime = 0;
let timerInterval;

// Create function to modify innerHTML

function print(txt) {
  document.getElementById("Timer").innerHTML = txt;
}

// Create "start", "pause" and "reset" functions

function start() {
  startTime = Date.now() - elapsedTime;
    timerInterval = setInterval(function printTime() {
      elapsedTime = Date.now() - startTime;
      print(timeToString(elapsedTime));
    }, 10)
}

function pause() {
  clearInterval(timerInterval);
}

// Create event listeners

let playButton = document.getElementById("playButton");
let pauseButton = document.getElementById("pauseButton");

playButton.addEventListener("click", start);
pauseButton.addEventListener("click", pause);
```

the method I save the json file goes like this:

```
document.getElementById("saveButton").addEventListener('click',()=>{
  //Save the counter here (there is a code above that counts click ignore this one, not related to the question)
  finalcurrenthunt.counter=counter;
  //save the timer here
  //timer save code (what variables do I need to save inside the json file in order to continue from where I paused the timer)
  //save the json to a selected folder 
  const huntsaved = JSON.stringify(finalcurrenthunt,null,2);
  const finalhuntsaved = huntsaved.replaceAll('\n',"")
  alert("Please Click On The Save File, When Asked To Replace Please Do So.")
  ipcRenderer.send("create-document-trigger",finalhuntsaved);
})
```

I want to save the timer once I pause it and when I exit the app and start it again, load the save file I will start from the value it was last saved.

example:
I used the timer until I reached 00:0025,
I saved the file when the timer at 00:00:25,
I want to use the timer again so I open the app and load the save file to continue from 00:00:25 instead of completely restarting the timer

how can I achieve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I store my countdown timer in a cookie so that it will continue counting down even when leaving or reloading the page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46312941/how-do-i-store-my-countdown-timer-in-a-cookie-so-that-it-will-continue-counting)

Answer (score 0):

My issue was pretty straight forward, I had to save elapsed time in a weird way I would say?

I pushed the let ElapsedTime to the top of my file (since everything you see here is at the bottom of my js)
I put on the pause function before clearing the Interval

```
saveTimer = ElapsedTime;
```

and went to my save method and added

```
finalcurrenthunt.timer=saveTimer;
```